# Is there something like .NET's T4 for Java?

Tags: java, code-generation

I'm helping a friend develop a Java application. They are a non-MS shop.
I was tasked to write some repetitive code, so naturally as a .NET dev I thought of using T4.

But I'm stuck on Java/Eclipse (and no C# is allowed) so what are my options?
What do Java people use for code generation? Build tasks?

Answer (score 3):

Take a peek at [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/)'s [Texen](http://velocity.apache.org/texen/releases/texen-1.0/) engine, connected to an [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) task.

Answer (score 3):

You  might also want to take a look at XText[1] and AndroMDA[2], both different from T4, but well suited to problems involving lots of repetitive-code.

[1] http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/
[2] http://www.andromda.org/index.php

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use something more "independent", check [AtomWeaver](http://www.atomweaver.com). This is basically a template engine like T4. However, it's independent from any platform or IDE, and while it lets you build simple templates to generate pieces of code, it can also be used to develop complete systems. The paradigm it follows is [ABSE](http://www.abse.info).

Answer (score 0):

Within Eclipse you might find templates useful. You can create new templates in the Preferences dialog via *Java>Editor>Templates*.

More targeted templates are configurable at *Java>CodeStyle>Code Templates*.

There's an introduction to templates in Eclipse in ["Effective Eclipse: Custom Templates"](http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/effective-eclipse-custom-templ), which covers both *Java>Editor>Templates* and *Web and XML -> XML Files -> Templates*. (I have not used the latter.)

Comment: I don't think this does what he asks? Templates are what in .Net is called snippets and are just predefined blocks of tekst with some field like experience (= you can jump easily between predefined positions in the tekst)